# RabbitMQ/Erlang crashing: Cannot reallocate 313760 bytes of memory (of type "code")

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

Can anyone please help to understand these crash logs?

RabbitMQ 3.6.6, Erlang 19.1
RabbitMQ is running on Microsoft Windows Web Server 2008 R2 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601 64bit.

RabbitMQ started to crash yesterday after running OK about one year. Now I have upgraded Erlang and RabbitMQ Server to the versions mentioned above but this did not change anything - still crashing
frequently.

.log:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 13-Dec-2016::22:13:55 ===
** Generic server rabbit_disk_monitor terminating
** Last message in was update
** When Server state == {state,"d:/ETOIMI~1/RabbitMQ/RABBIT~1",50000000,
                               14439952384,100,10000,#Ref<0.0.1.27257>,false,
                               true}
** Reason for termination ==
** {eacces,[{erlang,open_port,
                    [{spawn,"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c dir /-C /W \"d:/ETOIMI~1/RabbitMQ/RABBIT~1\""},
                     [binary,stderr_to_stdout,stream,in,hide]],
                    [{file,"erlang.erl"},{line,2080}]},
            {os,cmd,1,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,230}]},
            {rabbit_disk_monitor,get_disk_free,2,
                                 [{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
                                  {line,218}]},
            {rabbit_disk_monitor,internal_update,1,
                                 [{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
                                  {line,193}]},
            {rabbit_disk_monitor,handle_info,2,
                                 [{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
                                  {line,165}]},
            {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,601}]},
            {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,667}]},
            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
```

-sasl.log:

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 13-Dec-2016::22:13:55 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: rabbit_disk_monitor:init/1
    pid: <0.211.0>
    registered_name: rabbit_disk_monitor
    exception exit: {eacces,
                        [{erlang,open_port,
                             [{spawn,
                                  "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c dir /-C /W \"d:/ETOIMI~1/RabbitMQ/RABBIT~1\""},
                              [binary,stderr_to_stdout,stream,in,hide]],
                             [{file,"erlang.erl"},{line,2080}]},
                         {os,cmd,1,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,230}]},
                         {rabbit_disk_monitor,get_disk_free,2,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
                              {line,218}]},
                         {rabbit_disk_monitor,internal_update,1,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
                              {line,193}]},
                         {rabbit_disk_monitor,handle_info,2,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},
                              {line,165}]},
                         {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,601}]},
                         {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,667}]},
                         {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                             [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
      in function  gen_server:terminate/7 (gen_server.erl, line 812)
    ancestors: [rabbit_disk_monitor_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.164.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.210.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 6772
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 381464
  neighbours:

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 13-Dec-2016::22:13:55 ===
     Supervisor: {local,rabbit_disk_monitor_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     {eacces,
                     [{erlang,open_port,
                          [{spawn,
                               "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c dir /-C /W \"d:/ETOIMI~1/RabbitMQ/RABBIT~1\""},
                           [binary,stderr_to_stdout,stream,in,hide]],
                          [{file,"erlang.erl"},{line,2080}]},
                      {os,cmd,1,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,230}]},
                      {rabbit_disk_monitor,get_disk_free,2,
                          [{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,218}]},
                      {rabbit_disk_monitor,internal_update,1,
                          [{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,193}]},
                      {rabbit_disk_monitor,handle_info,2,
                          [{file,"src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl"},{line,165}]},
                      {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,
                          [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,601}]},
                      {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                          [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,667}]},
                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                          [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.211.0>},
                  {name,rabbit_disk_monitor},
                  {mfargs,{rabbit_disk_monitor,start_link,[50000000]}},
                  {restart_type,{transient,1}},
                  {shutdown,30000},
                  {child_type,worker}]
```

Also I have found Erlang crash dump, please see 
[HERE](https://www.upload.ee/download/6449051/d8888dbaf54e10d79432/erl_crash.dump)

If there is more information that should be provided by me please let me know.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`** {eacces,[{erlang,open_port,
                    [{spawn,"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c dir /-C /W \"d:/ETOIMI~1/RabbitMQ/RABBIT~1\""},`

`eacces` is an [Erlang error](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html):

> eacces Missing search or write permissions for the parent directories
>   of Dir.

most likely the service has problems to access here: `d:/ETOIMI~1/RabbitMQ/RABBIT~1\`

Comment: Well, since the permissions had not been changed before the crashes started, it doesn't feel very likely. But for any case I added full control to Everyone. RabbitMQ continued to crash.
Now I have noticed that some other application that runs on the same machine takes all the RAM exactly before RabbitMQ crashes. Took the other application offline and no crashes so far...
Also when you check the Erlang dump there is a line:
`Slogan: eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 2545496 bytes of memory (of type "heap").`